# Tension in a massless rope

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string

I have been really confused on the rxn pair of tension by a massless string on a an object or a man.[image]

[image]

(PLEASE NOTE THAT:-the 1,2,3 numbers i use in this question actually represent the parts of string i drew in the figure)

[image]

I am confused in action rxn pair of force applied by man on a string which is connected M mass at one end .
So i watched alot of youtube videos and quora answers and most of them explain the question by dividing the question in some segments.So I divided the string in Five parts in figure.
Mainly my question is related to part 1.

QUESTION:-(string is massless)
So lets assume F force is applied by man on the string part 1.
And a opposite force acts on part 1 by part 2 as attraction force which balances F applied on it.As string is massless.(for part 1 only)

F=ma if mass is zero then net force should also be zero on it.So NLM works finely here.But the string can accelerate as 0/0 is undefined.And it clearly shows in order to have net force zero (lets assume the attraction force is T)

F=T.....(i)

Now according to NEWTONS THIRD LAW every action has equal and opposite rxn which acts on different bodies.So the attraction force by 2 on 1 has rxn pair on part 2 by part 1.It continues like this upto part 5 of string (2 having force on 3 and 3 also having force on 2)so we can say tension at every point is T.(in massless string)

CASE 1:-
The F force acting on string 1 has rxn pair on the man F.
Now this is right if the man has no acceleration.

As F-F=ma

And he can also pull the object at another end even if he has no acceleration as the different part of strings can have acceleration of their own.so the parts move to bring the mass M closer to man.

CASE 2:-(problem arises acoording to me)
But the problem arises when we assume the man is also accelarating.

From eqn (i)

This eqn works in this case too.As string is massless and net force on every part of it should equal zero.

Since F is acting on 1 and it is balanced by T (attraction force between part 1 and 2)
The T again acts as rxn pair on part 2 by 1.

And The F acts as a rxn pair on the man.

So my question is how come he has acceleration if the forces acting on him balance each other.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140115/discussion-on-question-by-nishchal123-tension-in-a-massless-rope).

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is how come he has acceleration if the forces acting on him balance each other.

In your free body diagram it is important to draw all of the relevant forces on each free body. On the man there are three forces you neglected to include: gravity, the normal force, and friction. Gravity and the normal force cancel each other, so you can drop them from further consideration. But friction remains.

If the friction force differs in magnitude from the tension then the person will accelerate. If the forces do balance each other then he will not accelerate.

Comment: I am neglecting gravity because on sliding something it would have role if there was friction on it as normal force . But I am considering a smooth surface .

Comment: So in case of man there is only force acting on him which would be reaction force of the force he applied on string.which would make him accelerate towards the string??.

Comment: You should still include it on the diagram, even if you neglect it from then on. However, if the surface is smooth then there is no friction and the person accelerates because there is an unbalanced horizontal force.

Comment: Would the acceleration be towards string as the only force acting on him would be reaction pair of him applying force on string??

Comment: He is not really applying a force F on the string. It is massless. The string simply is a conduit for delivering the force to the mass. The reaction force pair in this case is the mass exerting a force -F on the man.

Comment: @Rod Bhar so sir is my figure incorrect.I also have tried to demonstrate the exact logic you said by dividing it into little segments which shows the force is transfered to the block as tension which gives the block a acceleration but what i amn't understanding is the tension force gets canceled everywhere without the one accelerating the block at the other end.So i assumed the reaction force by string's part 1 acts as tension .

Comment: The tension in a string between two forces $F_1$ and $F_2$ is $T=2 \dfrac{F_1\cdot F_2}{F_1+F_2} $. You can see that if $F_1$ and $F_2$ have different values, the value of T will not equal either but will be intermediate.

Comment: https://youtu.be/VXu2gatnMWE sir can you check out his video i just modified it a little bit in my question.

Comment: @RodBhar the person is applying a force on the massless rope. The OP is fully justified in describing that force and also in subdividing the rope and talking about the forces on an individual segment of the rope

Comment: @Dale Well, I suppose you can subdivide the massless string, but I don't see how it adds to understanding since the tension will be the same throughout. Why not consider it to be one unit?

Comment: @RodBhar that is a technique that is often used in statics and dynamics for analyzing structures of all sorts, including suspension bridges and other structures with flexible members. It is necessary for massive cables, but it also works for massless cables. Furthermore, the OP analyzed it correctly. I would not criticize a correct analysis.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to understand if we skip the string for a moment. Suppose the man is positively charge, and the mass is negatively charged. The man and mass will exert an attractive force on each other.

You can see how Newton's $3$rd law applies. The force on the man and the force on the mass are equal and opposite. The forces on the man are not balanced. Neither are those on the mass.

If there are no other forces (Suppose the man and mass are on ice.), then they will accelerate toward each other. If they remain stationary, it is because the total force on each is $0$. For example if they are on the ground, the force of friction will oppose the attractive force.

---

So how does it work when the force comes from a string?

First, every string has mass. In problems like this, we ignore the mass to simplify the calculation of acceleration. This is just to make it easier to understand the physics. It is confusing enough to calculate the acceleration of two masses. A problem where man, string, and mass are all accelerating would teach you about the same physics but would be less clear. In more advanced classes, the mass of the string might be included if it helped learn about more advanced topics.

Also, if the mass of the string is small, the answer comes out close enough to the real answer that you wouldn't see the difference. Physicists make this kind of approximation all the time.

You shouldn't need to use the "fact" that the string is massless to understand how forces work in a string. They work the same if the string has mass. It will matter when you calculate how big those forces are.

For this kind of problem, we want the string to be a gadget that just transmits force. If the man pulls on the string with a force T, the string pulls on the mass with the same force T. Likewise, the mass pulls on the string with force T and the string pulls on the man with force T. If you can ignore how the string works and the string doesn't change the force, thinking about the problem gets simpler.

To think about the string as a gadget, we should understand how the gadget works. And we need to understand why the string needs to be massless so it doesn't change the forces.

---

You understand how the string works. You divided it up into a chain of blocks. Each block exerts a force on the block next to it, and feels an equal and opposite force from that neighbor block. So the man pulls on block 1, block $1$ pulls on block $2$, ..., and block $5$ pulls on the mass.

The mass pulls on block $5$ with an equal and opposite force, which pulls ...

The only force on the man is from block $1$. It is not balanced. The only force on the mass is from block $5$. Again not balanced. The man and mass will accelerate toward each other.

---

The string needs to be massless so the forces at both ends are the same when things accelerate. To see this, we will contrive an easy situation with a massive "string". We will just use one block as the string. If you like, connect the man - ideal string - block - another ideal string - mass. So the massive string is two ideal strings with a massive block in the middle.

The man is standing on the ground. He remains stationary. The block and mass are on ice. They accelerate toward the man when he pulls. They both have the same acceleration, $a$.

The force the man exerts is $T_1 = (m_b + m_m)a$. This is the tension in the first string.

The force the block exerts on the mass is $T_2 = m_ma$.

The force in the two ends of a massive string are the same if $(m_b + m_m)a = m_ma$. That is, if either $m_b = 0$ or $a = 0$

Comment: I found out that tension is actually not action rxn pair of the force exerted on the rope but a force of attraction.So in order for block b to accelerate the tension exerted in it should be low then the F trying to accelerate it. So on this assumption I took tension as action on block and block exerting equal reaction on string.                                                     But if I think this problem a little bit differently an assumed F is applied on segment 1 which would have same tension T acting.Then again the block doesn't seem to be accelerating again.Is this physics inconsistency

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/267987/conceptual-doubt-in-tension-force .The only possible solution is provided by you either the mass of b should be zero or the system shouldn't be acceleratin.You should go to this link to actually view what I am referring