# What does it mean by tension in string?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, definition, education, string

My teacher told me, when you pluck the string which is being stretched from two sides, it means there is tension in it.

When I compress it from both ends, there is no tension in it.

What does that mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we define tension in a string as the reactive force produced in a string being pulled at both ends?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/166518/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tension refers to the pulling force transmitted axially by the means of a string, cable, chain, or similar one-dimensional continuous object like string;

tension might also be described as the action-reaction pair of forces acting at each end of the said elements.like in your case this tension force is opposing an extension in string.

When you compress the string there is a case of slagging I.e string is loose and no tension force develops

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/166518/can-we-define-tension-in-a-string-as-the-reactive-force-produced-in-a-string-bei?rq=1 and